# Trouble with kernel in kernlab R package

Tags: r, svm, kernel-trick

I'm using [kernlab package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kernlab/index.html)

Here are two examples:
First:

```
library(kernlab)
x <- runif(1020, 1, 5000)
y <- sqrt(x)
model.vanilla <- rvm(x, y, kernel='vanilladot')
```

Got error:

```
Error in chol.default(crossprod(Kr)/var + diag(1/thetatmp)) :
the leading minor of order 2 is not positive definite
```

Second:

```
library(kernlab)
x <- runif(1020, 1, 5000)
y <- sqrt(x)
model.rbf <- rvm(x[1:1000], y[1:1000], kernel='rbfdot')
print(model.rbf)
py.rbf <- predict(model.rbf, x[1001:1020])
print(paste("MSE: ", sum((py.rbf - y[1001:1020]) ^ 2) / length(py.rbf)))
```

OK:

```
Using automatic sigma estimation (sigest) for RBF or laplace kernel 
Relevance Vector Machine object of class "rvm" 
Problem type: regression 

Gaussian Radial Basis kernel function. 
 Hyperparameter : sigma =  5.44268665122008e-06 

Number of Relevance Vectors : 247 
Variance :  4.368e-06
Training error : 3.418e-06 
[1] "MSE:  4.921706631013e-05"
```

Why doesn't using linear kernel work here? `polydot` (polynomial kernel function) doesn't work either.

Can this be fixed?

Comment: @NickCox Thanks for your answer. I don't think that it's bug in software. And i have no problems with programming here. I suppose it has something to do with the algorithm(rvm) and data type. But anything is possible... Second example work fine.

Comment: Does it make any difference if you add a small amount of noise to your y?

Comment: @Wayne slightly worse prediction with `rbfdot` kernel(MSE ~ 6) and still error with `vanilladot`

Comment: @NickCox I thought that this could be due to preprocessing data...

Comment: I've removed my previous comments about seeming off-topic (and retracted my close vote). The accepted answer is that the input data appear unsuitable and I take that to indicate a statistical issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Evidently, your data is too sparse for that combination of method and kernel. If you change your

```
x <- runif(1020, 1, 5000)
```

to either of

```
x <- runif(10200, 1, 5000)
x <- runif(1020, 1, 100)
```

it works. For me.